# Is there a typo is this lecture? (Hidden Markov Models)

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Lecture in question: https://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~jcorso/t/CSE555/files/lecture_hmm.pdf
Slide #6 shows this graph:
[image]
Slide #7 gives these probabilities:
[image]

**Is P(Dry|High) = 0.3 on slide #7 a typo?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  If there are only two observable states ("Rain" and "Dry"), then the conditional probabilities given high barometric pressure must add to $1$; thus Slide #7 as written is not self-consistent.

Comment: Looking at the graph, would the proper value for P(Dry|High) be 0.6?

Comment: I assume P(Rain|Low) and P(Dry|Low) add up to 1, so P(Rain|High) and P(Dry|High) must add up to 1 as well. Since P(Rain|High) is 0.4, P(Dry|High) must be 0.6?